# How can i get input values in loop using jquery?

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I search more times but not get any idea,

Here is HTML:

```
       {% for pr in productlist %}
       <div class="grid-container">
          <span>
            <label> {{ pr.productname }} </label>
            <label name="mylist" class="prprice" id="prprice"> {{ pr.price1 }} </label>
          </span>
          <section class="sec">
            <input type="number" name="mylist" class="prnumber" id="prnumber">
          </section>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
```

I can get `price` (id : prprice) one by one in loop via : `price = parseFloat($(this).parents('span').find('label:eq(1)').text());`

It is my full jQuery also :

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 {
    $("#tabSum").click(function(){
        var price = 0;
        var number = 0;

        $(".grid-container").each(function() {
            
            price = parseFloat($(this).parents('span').find('label:eq(1)').text());
            
            number = parseFloat($('.sec').find("input[name='mylist']").val()); <-- problem
     });  
 });
```

My problem is that i want get all number (id : prnumber) elements one by one (like price) but it returned first element only, what is wrong here?

Comment: Ids have to be unique

Comment: @Andreas but i dont use Ids

Comment: This is true (hence a comment and not an answer), but you still generate invalid markup.

Comment: @Andreas please explain more , what i do must?

Comment: For example add the product id to the element id like id="prprice_{{pr.id}}" or even set no id if you never use it

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff my problem is with numbers not price

Comment: You forgot the $this in the query so its always finding the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to avoid looping you could do :

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 {
    $("#tabSum").click(function(){
       var prices = $("label.prprice").map((i,e) => parseFloat($(e).text())).get();

       var numbers = $("input.prnumber").map((i,e) => parseFloat($(e).val())).get();
     });
 });
```

so you trap all prices in array prices and all numbers in array numbers  in the same order

after if you want to have the result price * number, just loop over array:

```
  var mult =[]
  for (let i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
     if(Number.isNaN(numbers[i]) continue;//avoid NaN values, test for prices too if needed
     mult[i] = prices[i] * numbers[i];
  }
```

to have sum after

```
 var sum = mult.reduce((a, b) => a + b );
```

Comment: replace text by val, i dont see how are stocked your number

Comment: thanks, worked. If i want to use list that selected by checkboxes how to write price and numbers? i can get list via ```// $("input[name='mylistch']:checked").each(function() )``` but don't know how to filter.

Comment: $("input[name='mylistch']:checked").each(function() {.console.log($(this) .attr("id"));}   display id for example

Comment: Also how can get sum of all mult in list?

Comment: @hami   you use reduce to do the sum of an array

Comment: you have Nan because you havent set all input?

Comment: add line of code in loop for mult  test if value is NaN

Answer (score 0):

You forgot $this so it will always find the first element

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#tabSum").click(function(){
        var price = 0;
        var number = 0;

        $(".grid-container").each(function() {
        
            price = parseFloat($(this).parents('span').find('label:eq(1)').text());
        
            number = parseFloat($(this).find("input[name='mylist']").val()); <-- problem
         });  
     });
});
```

This should work (untested)

Comment: this is good but you forget how to address to ```prnumber``` , result of this is NaN